# Neo4j cypher how to stop recursivity at first match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Considering a graph like this:

```
START -> A -> B -> C {attr: X} -> D {attr: X}
```

I would like to retrieve the paths from START to first item where attr is 'X'

I tried to search a bit and modifying queries I found, but no luck. Doing this will return 2 paths:

```
MATCH p=(START)-[*1..]->(n:node {attr:X}) RETURN p
```

I tried this but no luck:

```
MATCH p=(START)-[*1..]->(n:node {attr:X}) 
WHERE SINGLE(x in nodes(p) WHERE x.attr = X) 
RETURN P
```

But this still returns 2 paths.

How can I get only the path I want ?

Another way to see it could be to get only the longest path (stopping at D node). If I am sure D is a leaf, how can I get only the path stopping at the leaf ? In this last case it will retrieve the longest one but only one.

Thanks a lot
Rémi

**EDIT**

In fact to be more precise, I do not want only the shortest or the longest path between 2 nodes, so LIMIT is not a solution.
I want either:

- all the paths between START and the first nodes having attr:X
- OR all the paths between START and the last notdes having attr:X

One real example can be this, START is the brown node at the bottom and nodes having attr:X are the 2 yellow ones at top.

[image: graph_example]

In this example, we have 8 paths between START and nodes having attr:X. I want to have only 4, either stoping at the first yellow node, or stoping at the last, but never both.

Thanks

Comment: Try to use limit

Comment: Which do you really want: the shortest path to `X`, the longest path to `X`, the (shortest or longest) path to a specific node with `X`, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found my mistakes and finally make it working.

Thanks a lot cybersam for your help.

My solution is:

1. For the paths stopping at first occurence:

Usage of single

```
MATCH p = (START)-[*]->(n:node {attr:X})
WHERE SINGLE (n IN NODES(p) WHERE EXISTS(n.attr) AND n.attr = X)
RETURN p
```

I noticed for this one that `SINGLE (n IN NODES(p) WHERE n.attr = X)` does not work, since attr does not exists in all nodes along the path.

2. For the paths stopping at leaf:

Solution given by cybersam works perfectly

```
MATCH p = (START)-[*]->(n:node {attr:X})
WHERE NOT (n)-->()
RETURN p
```

Rémi

Answer (score 3):

These examples might be helpful.

To find a single shortest path to the first `node` with `X` (which I assume is defined earlier in the query):

```
MATCH p = (START)-[*]->(n:node {attr:X})
WHERE NOT ANY (n IN NODES(p)[..-1] WHERE 'node' IN LABELS(n) AND n.attr = X)
RETURN p
ORDER BY LENGTH(p)
LIMIT 1
```

To find a single shortest path to a leaf `node` with `X`:

```
MATCH p = (START)-[*]->(n:node {attr:X})
WHERE NOT (n)-->()
RETURN p
ORDER BY LENGTH(p)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: In fact I do not want only shortest or longest path, see my post edit above. I want to keep all the paths, and trying your queries without LIMIT still gives me 8 paths instead of 4 as I want.